# How do I wait for a setTimeout in the exit callback for proccess using node?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code...

```
async function finish(){
    console.log("Finishing");
    console.time("fin");
    let test = await new Promise(function(res){
         setTimeout(()=>{res(test)}, 2000);
    });
    console.timeEnd("fin");
    console.log(test);
};
process.on('exit', finish);
```

I would expect this to wait two second on exit and print out a timestamp close to 2s. However, when I run the timestamp is shorter and doesn't print any line after Finishing.

How do I wait for a timeout on exit?

Comment: Your function is erroring within the Promise because `test` is `undefined`. Try `setTimeout(()=>{res()}, 2000);` instead

Comment: What you are trying to do is explicitly stated to not work in the node docs: [process API](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit)

Comment: @sjagr that was merely a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit), you cannot use asynchronous code in the exit event.

> Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations. The Node.js process will exit immediately after calling the 'exit' event listeners causing any additional work still queued in the event loop to be abandoned.

If you want to schedule additional work before exiting (e.g. your asynchronous function), you need to use [beforeExit](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_beforeexit).

```
process.on('beforeExit', finish);
```

Having said that, you'll also need to recognize that beforeExit is only emitted when the process is out of work to do, so a) it'll not emit if something explicitly calls for termination (e.g. process.exit()) and b) it'll keep emitting unless that happens.

Comment: So it probably also doesn't get called if there is an error thrown right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe that's correct.  If you want to have a catch-all error handler, check out [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) and [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection)